# What's the term for a group of people who enjoy literary works?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, paired-word-requests, korean

I'm translating an essay to English from Korean, and it uses the term *hyangyoo jibdan*, which means "a group of people who enjoy literary works". What's the English term for that?

(I've searched, but I couldn't find anything.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because my understanding is that translation requests are off-topic for this Stack.

Comment: I think *book club* can be used, even if the members aren't restricted to just books.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin. The main question "What's the term for a group of people who enjoy literary works" requires no knowledge of Korean so I think it's valid. I would see the information that it's a translation as further context. I'm commenting, because it's something I am a bit unsure of myself. Sometimes I have questions which arises due to a translation, but are not requests for a translation. I'm never sure if I should mention what the original context was in case someone suggest it be closed.

Comment: This is ambiguous. Is it the general kind of people who enjoy this or is it a specific set of a few people (and do they meet to discuss these readings)? Is 'literary works ' -any kind of reading, classics, comic books, newspapers, or just one special set of them? Add any details you can.

Comment: I would say "bookies".

Comment: @HotLicks lol. If that makes it into a translated work, you will be hounded by the Language Furies to the end of your days!

Comment: @Jeff see the [translation tag description](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation)

Comment: If the group is somewhat organized, you could call it a literature appreciation society, although these usually have a more specific focus, e.g. the Iain Banks Appreciation Society: http://www.iainbanks.org/

Comment: Nerds?  Or, more appropriately,  "NEEEEEERRRRRDDDS!"

Comment: Hi Magnolia, it still isn't clear which you mean, a group that meets together to discuss books, or rather just the kind of people who enjoy books (no meeting involved at all)? Also, what kind of reading: belles lettres, romance, scifi, manga?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know any Korean, but answering the question's title, I would call it a **circle**.
Lexico has [this](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/circle)

> **circle**
>   NOUN
>
> **2** A group of people with a shared profession, interests, or acquaintances.
>   *His court became the centre for a dazzling circle of poets.*

So you could say

> My [literature circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_circle) meets every Tuesday.

Answer (score 8):

Bibliophile.

From [Wikipedia's entry on Bibliophilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibliophilia):

> ... a bibliophile or bookworm is an individual who loves and frequently reads books...

The plural is bibliophiles. Of course, this terminology may not be exactly what you want, if you mean a group of people who interact with each other, like in a book club. But other than a more casual term like "book lovers", it's the closest term available for someone who loves books.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest ‘literary enthusiasts’.  Which would cover anyone who is keen on literature.

If you wanted to be witty, and a bit sarcastic, you could describe them as the ‘literati’. Which isn’t really a word, but everyone will know what you mean, because it sounds like glitterati, which means, the elite, educated, upper class etc.  Then, they’d sound like glamourous people who rush around to book events, drinking champagne and listening to authors. ...Which hopefully, they do!

https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/glitterati

Comment: What makes you say *literati* isn't a word? Did you look it up? See [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literati). Your reference to *glitterati* seems misplaced.

Comment: In fact, _glitterati_ (and _Twitterati_ and similar) were derived **from** the much-earlier _literati_.  So _literati_ seems like the historically-correct answer.

Comment: Oh yeah I knew I was forgetting something

Comment: As an aside, I did coin ‘clitterati’ when a friend was describing a porno convention. It was remembering that conversation that confused me about where the heck did the original ‘ati’  word come from!  Although, that too, on googling it, might be appropriate here, seeming to mean ‘women writers with a focus on sexuality’ and not... the meaning I created. Sniff.

Answer (score 4):

I think it might depend on whether it's a group that interact with one another. I upvoted the "literature circle" answer, but if it is a group who don't necessarily know one another (e.g a group of people who write letters to a literary magazine independently of one another)
I'd suggest *literature buffs*.

[buff](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/buff?s=t)

> a devotee or well-informed student of some activity or subject: Civil
>   War buffs avidly read the new biography of Grant.

.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of work with [Hong’s Hangul Conversion Tools](https://sori.org/hangul/conv2kr.cgi) gave me the Hangul for your phrase; I had to transliterate it in the JAMO-to-KR as “HyanGyu jibdan”, which gave me the Unicode hangul rendered below in the image. When I pasted the Unicode text into [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ko&tl=en&text=%ED%96%A5%EC%9C%A0%20%EC%A7%91%EB%8B%A8), it rendered it as “Enjoyment Group”

[image: Hangul for jamos HYAN GYU JIB DAN]

Comment: So that would translate as an "appreciation society" then.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context, it may be appropriate to say a **literary [salon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salon_(gathering))**.

Salon has a connotation of learning about and creating artistic work, as opposed to just enjoying it. To me it calls to mind the Paris salon that Gertrude Stein hosted in the early 1900's.